# create simple toast notifications and chain them in a row from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I am trying to create toast notifications, for the most part, my code is working fine enough. However, I am struggling to position my toasts on top of everything else in the page, so that toast #1 appears on top of everything in the top of the page, toast #2 appears on top of everything, but will be stacked under toast #1, etc.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSuccess").click(function() {
    createSuccessToast("everything is fine");
  });

  $("#btnError").click(function() {
    createErrorToast("something went wrong");
  });
});

function createSuccessToast(toastMessage) {
  createToast(true, toastMessage);
}

function createErrorToast(toastMessage) {
  createToast(false, toastMessage);
}

function createToast(isSuccess, toastMessage) {
  var toastContainer = createToastContainer(isSuccess);
  createToastHeader(toastContainer, isSuccess);
  createToastContent(toastContainer, toastMessage);
  initToast(toastContainer);
  destroyToast(toastContainer);
}

function createToastContainer(isSuccess) {
  var toastContainer = $("<div></div>");
  toastContainer.addClass("toastContainer");
  if (isSuccess) {
    toastContainer.addClass("toastContainerSuccess");
  } else {
    toastContainer.addClass("toastContainerError");
  }
  return toastContainer;
}

function createToastHeader(toastContainer, isSuccess) {
  var toastHeader = $("<div></div>");
  toastHeader.addClass("toastHeader");
  toastHeader.html(isSuccess ? "Success" : "Error");
  toastContainer.append(toastHeader);
}

function createToastContent(toastContainer, toastMessage) {
  var toastContent = $("<div></div>");
  toastContent.addClass("toastContent");
  toastContent.html(toastMessage);
  toastContainer.append(toastContent);
}

function initToast(toastContainer) {
  toastContainer.hide(function() {
    $(document.body).append(toastContainer);
    toastContainer.fadeIn(500);
  });
}

function destroyToast(toastContainer) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    toastContainer.fadeOut(500, function() {
      toastContainer.remove();
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.toastContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.toastContainerSuccess {
  background-color: #99ff33;
}

.toastContainerError {
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

.toastHeader {}

.toastContent {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnSuccess">
Success
</button>

<button id="btnError">
Error
</button>
```

To achieve my desired results, I added 2 CSS properties to `.toastContainer`:

1. `position: absolute;`
2. `z-index: 1;`

But then, all toasts would spawn at the exact same location on the page, so if there were multiple toasts, only the most recent would be visible.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want the notifications to appear above the buttons?

Comment: yes, you're right

Comment: Your question is poorly worded.

Comment: I will update my answer if you could provide suggestions

Comment: @Question3r I edited it instead.

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Comment: @Question3r I have added the answer, if am not right you were trying to achieve the same.

Comment: @Question3r BTW OP, I had also refactored your code and I just posted it in Codereview, you should take a look: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184013/toast-mini-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should append the toasts to a container element which is `position: absolute; z-index: 1` instead (because if multiple elements are `position: absolute`, and they have the same top/left positions, they WILL appear on top of another, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSuccess").click(function() {
    createSuccessToast("everything is fine");
  });

  $("#btnError").click(function() {
    createErrorToast("something went wrong");
  });
});

function createSuccessToast(toastMessage) {
  createToast(true, toastMessage);
}

function createErrorToast(toastMessage) {
  createToast(false, toastMessage);
}

function createToast(isSuccess, toastMessage) {
  var toastContainer = createToastContainer(isSuccess);
  createToastHeader(toastContainer, isSuccess);
  createToastContent(toastContainer, toastMessage);
  initToast(toastContainer);
  destroyToast(toastContainer);
}

function createToastContainer(isSuccess) {
  var toastContainer = $("<div></div>");
  toastContainer.addClass("toastContainer");
  if (isSuccess) {
    toastContainer.addClass("toastContainerSuccess");
  } else {
    toastContainer.addClass("toastContainerError");
  }
  return toastContainer;
}

function createToastHeader(toastContainer, isSuccess) {
  var toastHeader = $("<div></div>");
  toastHeader.addClass("toastHeader");
  toastHeader.html(isSuccess ? "Success" : "Error");
  toastContainer.append(toastHeader);
}

function createToastContent(toastContainer, toastMessage) {
  var toastContent = $("<div></div>");
  toastContent.addClass("toastContent");
  toastContent.html(toastMessage);
  toastContainer.append(toastContent);
}

function initToast(toastContainer) {
  toastContainer.hide(function() {
    $("#toastsContainer").append(toastContainer);
    toastContainer.fadeIn(500);
  });
}

function destroyToast(toastContainer) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    toastContainer.fadeOut(500, function() {
      toastContainer.remove();
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
#toastsContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.toastContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.toastContainerSuccess {
  background-color: #99ff33;
}

.toastContainerError {
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

.toastHeader {}

.toastContent {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnSuccess">
Success
</button>

<button id="btnError">
Error
</button>

<div id="toastsContainer"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, great example!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, I have used the global variable pos, and accordingly set the position of the buttons dynamically after the button click, and after the fade out the buttons will move back to the previous position again.

```js
var pos = 80;
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btnSuccess").click(function() {

document.getElementById("btnSuccess").style.top= ""+pos+"px";
document.getElementById("btnError").style.top= ""+pos+"px";
pos = pos + 80;

createSuccessToast("everything is fine");
});

$("#btnError").click(function() {
document.getElementById("btnSuccess").style.top= ""+pos+"px";
document.getElementById("btnError").style.top= ""+pos+"px";
pos = pos + 80;
createErrorToast("something went wrong");
});
});

function createSuccessToast(toastMessage) {
createToast(true, toastMessage);
}

function createErrorToast(toastMessage) {
createToast(false, toastMessage);
}

function createToast(isSuccess, toastMessage) {
var toastContainer = createToastContainer(isSuccess);
createToastHeader(toastContainer, isSuccess);
createToastContent(toastContainer, toastMessage);
initToast(toastContainer);
destroyToast(toastContainer);
}

function createToastContainer(isSuccess) {
var toastContainer = $("<div></div>");
toastContainer.addClass("toastContainer");
if (isSuccess) {
toastContainer.addClass("toastContainerSuccess");
} else {
toastContainer.addClass("toastContainerError");
}
return toastContainer;
}

function createToastHeader(toastContainer, isSuccess) {
var toastHeader = $("<div></div>");
toastHeader.addClass("toastHeader");
toastHeader.html(isSuccess ? "Success" : "Error");
toastContainer.append(toastHeader);
}

function createToastContent(toastContainer, toastMessage) {
var toastContent = $("<div></div>");
toastContent.addClass("toastContent");
toastContent.html(toastMessage);
toastContainer.append(toastContent);
}

function initToast(toastContainer) {
toastContainer.hide(function() {
$(document.body).append(toastContainer);
toastContainer.fadeIn(500);
});
}

function destroyToast(toastContainer) {

setTimeout(function() {

pos = pos - 160;

toastContainer.fadeOut(500, function() {
document.getElementById("btnSuccess").style.top= ""+pos+"px";
document.getElementById("btnError").style.top= ""+pos+"px";
toastContainer.remove();
pos = pos + 80;

});
}, 5000);
}
```

```css
.toastContainer {
bottom:20px;

position:relative;
z-index:1;
margin-top: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px;
color: #ffffff;
}

#btnSuccess{
position:relative;
}
#btnError{
position:relative;
}
.toastContainerSuccess {
background-color: #99ff33;
}

.toastContainerError {
background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

.toastHeader {}

.toastContent {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnSuccess">
    Success
</button>

<button id="btnError">
    Error
</button>
```

Comment: It is really hard to update the existing styles with this solution.

Comment: I have used Javascript to dynamically position the elements, if you are good with Javascript then it is not tough to create much more better dynamic content rather than only using CSS.

Comment: [brittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_brittleness) is the correct term. E.g try to increase the padding by 10px, the code will break; I want to move the buttons to the bottom of the page, the code will break; etc.